# How to pass and return a pointer to an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, structure

I have an array of structures and the structure looks as below:

```c
struct patient {
    int pictures[2];
    int personal_number;
    char patient_name[FILE_PATIENT_NAMES + 1];
    int num_of_matches;
};

typedef struct patient Patient;

Patient patientregister[5];
```

I have two functions as down below:

```c
/********* function declaration *********/

Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients);
Patient *search_by_personaNumber(Patient *matches[],
                                 Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients);
```

The code starts from `*search_patient` and then goes to `*search_by_personalNumber`. `*search_patient` has another array of structures declared inside it: `Patient matches[5];` and the idea is to send a pointer of `Patient matches[5];` to `*search_by_personalNumber`. and then get it back to `*search_patient` with the matches the user is searching for. My question is how to send a pointer of an array of structures to another function, use the pointer to fill in the array of structures and send the pointer back to the original function, in my case `*search_patient`?

Comment: The formal parameter `Patient *matches[]` will never be compliant an argument from `Patient matches[5]` in any way whatsoever. Either the argument, or the formal parameter has to change somehow. Regardless, as we have no idea what this code is even supposed to be doing, we can't honestly assist further than pointing out that non-trivial fact. I *suspect* you're confusing a "pointer to an array of structures" with an "array of pointers to structures", but the fog is pretty thick to make that wild assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are implicitly (with rare exceptions) converted to pointers to their first elements in expressions.

So if in the function `search_patient` you declared an array like this

```
Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients)
{
    Patient matches[5];
    //...
}
```

then to pass it to the function `search_by_personaNumber` you can the following way

```
Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients)
{
    Patient matches[5];
    //...

    search_by_personaNumber( matches, 5 );
    //...
}
```

In fact there is no need in the function `search_patient` to use the return value of the function `search_by_personaNumber`. But if you indeed need to use it then you can write

```
Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients)
{
    Patient matches[5];
    //...

    Patient *p = search_by_personaNumber( matches, 5 );
    //...
}
```